# Xamarin ios song does not always play on speaker

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, azure-cognitive-services

I am user Xamarin fomrs text to speech api [click here to see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-text-to-speech?pivots=programming-language-csharp&tabs=script%2Cwindowsinstall)

I have manage to implemented it on my app but some time the song play on phone speaker and some speak on earphone after record the song

Question:

**How to make the song always play on phone's speaker**

Here is the code :

```
var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("xxxx", "xxxx");

config.SpeechSynthesisVoiceName = MicosoftTranslater.MySpeakerlanguagesList( "fr-FR");
var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(config);
await synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync("I am playing from phone speaker");
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Could it help you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is calling the `SetCategory` with the appropriate `AVAudioSessionCategory` and setting the session to active.

Like:

```
var session = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance();
session.SetCategory(AVAudioSessionCategory.Playback);
session.SetActive(true);
```

You could use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to set it in your ios project.You could refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/320860/isimpleaudioplayer-issues-on-ios-and-with-speechre.html.

Comment: Leo Zhu AVAudioSession.SharedInstance is not recognize in my xamarin forms code file